# len() of a function in python

Tags: python, function

I have a function that generally accepts lists, but on occasions needs to accept functions as well. There were several ways of dealing with this, but it would have been very very useful to be able to do `len(foo)` for a given function `foo`.

In the end, instead of passing in functions, I passed in callable classes that had a `__len__` function defined. But it got me thinking, since in python everything is an object, and functions can have attributes etc. just as a curiosity...

**Question**

Is there any way to give a function a len? A quick google didn't bring up anything.

**My attempt**

```
def foo():
    return True

def my_len(self):
    return 5

foo.__len__ = my_len

len(foo)
```

Comment: adding `__len__` on the _instance_ doesn't work, even for an object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642434/is-there-a-way-to-implement-methods-like-len-or-eq-as-classmethods

Comment: this isn't related. foo is an instance, not a class here.

Comment: @ChristianDean first, congrats for the python gold. _but_ the approaches mentionned in the "original" question don't work for special classes like `function`

Comment: Already on it @Jean-FrançoisFabre :-)

Comment: Gold badge works both ways :)

Comment: It wasn't a bad dupe. The OP already has a solution anyway, and the dupe explained why adding `__len__` to `foo` doesn't work. The reason why I personally don't like it as a dupe target is because  adding a `__len__` method to `foo` is just one possible "solution". There might be other ways to do it.

Comment: What does your function do that it might try to compute the length of a function, but not try to call a list? I think your code needs some redesign rather than a function with a `__len__` method.

Comment: @chepner I agree, it was more a curiosity. But one practical application might be iterating through a list of iterables, but only iterating through the 'inner iterables' below a certain length. If some of those iterables are lists and some are generators, it might be helpful to be able to estimate the 'length' of the generator before hand.

Comment: No @Aran-Fey, I didn't think it was a bad one either. But as Jean said, it wasn't really a necessary dupe as the alternative solution' didn't work with certain objects. Also, are you sure "There might be other ways to do it"? I'm pretty sure there aren't. Like [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557079/making-len-work-with-instance-methods/36557192#36557192) says: _"Python always looks up special methods through the object's class."_

Comment: @Tim A function and a generator are two very different things. Besides, Python provides `__length_hint__` for that use case.

Comment: @chepner yes, the example was more to give a sense of the original use case without a very very lengthy explanation, and in the original use case, I did need functions not generators. However I was not aware of `__length_hint__` that may well come in useful elsewhere. Thankyou :)

Comment: @ChristianDean Well, it depends on how you read the question. If the question is strictly just "How can I make `len(foo)` work?", then there probably is no way to do it. But if the question is "How can I make my function work with containers _and_ callables?", then there are a few ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `__len__` to an object is not working (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557079/making-len-work-with-instance-methods) added by Aran-Fey why). A function is just an object defining a `__call__` method. You can define a class like this:

```
class Foo:
  def __call__(self):
    return True
  def __len__(self):
    return 5
```

Using it:

```
>>> foo=Foo()
>>> foo()
True
>>> len(foo)
5
```

It is possible to create a function which is having a `length`, but you should consider the use case. Python gives you a lot of power, but not everything what's possible is actually a good idea.

Comment: "Adding __len__ to an object is not working" but why? (honest question, I don't know either :))

Comment: I have read that somewhere: len doesn't always check for `__len__` method. But can't find the reference. Your workaround is good.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557079/making-len-work-with-instance-methods

Comment: okay: "Special methods such as __len__ (double-underscore or "dunder" methods) must be defined on the class. They won't work if only defined on the instance."

Comment: it seems that none of the recipies work here (with a function). Or I'm not doing that properly: `inst.__class__ = type(_cls.__name__, (_cls,), {meth: lm})
TypeError: type 'function' is not an acceptable base type`

Comment: related but not dupe target: doesn't solve it, because `function` or `traceback` objects aren't "acceptable" as a base type.

Comment: Ah, okay @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I didn't look carefully enough, my bad.