# Can I replace an existing method of an object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

**Q:** Is there a way to alter a method of an existing object in Python (3.6)? (By "method" I mean a function that is passed `self` as an argument.)

---

**Example**

Let's say I have a class `Person` having some very useful method `SayHi()`:

```
class Person(object):
    Cash = 100
    def HasGoodMood(self):
        return self.Cash > 10

    def SayHi(self):
        if self.HasGoodMood():
            print('Hello!')
        else:
            print('Hmpf.')

>>> joe = Person()
>>> joe.SayHi()
Hello!
```

As you can see, the response of the person depends on their current mood computed by the method `HasGoodMood()`. A default person has good mood whenever they have more than 10$ cash on them.

I can easily create a person who does not care about the money and is happy all the time:

```
>>> joe.HasGoodMood = lambda: True
>>> joe.SayHi()
Hello!
>>> joe.Cash = 0
>>> joe.SayHi()
Hello!
```

Cool. Notice how Python knows that when using the original implementation of `HasGoodMood`, it passes silently `self` as the first argument, but if I change it to `lambda: True`, it calls the function with no arguments. The problem is: What if I want to change the default `HasGoodMood` for another function which would also accept `self` as a parameter?

Let's continue our example: what if I want to create a greedy `Person` who is only happy if they have more than 100$ on them? I would like to do something like:

```
>>> greedy_jack = Person()
>>> greedy_jack.HasGoodMood = lambda self: self.Cash > 100
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Is there some other way to change a method?

---

**Disclaimer:** The above example is just for demonstration purposes. I know that I could use inheritance or keep a cash threshold as a property of the `Person`. But that is not the point of the question.

Comment: @Arne that dupe is pretty out of date, it refers to Python 2 only.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Does it not work in 3 any more?

Comment: @Arne There is some info relevant to Python 3 there, but it's not obvious. In fact, it's not easy to tell when most of those answers are talking about old-style vs new-style classes.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the top 3 answers in Arne's dupe do apply to python 3. I don't see anything wrong with that dupe target.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Fair enough. And Aaron's answer was written with Python 3 in mind.

Comment: What about `greedy_jack.HasGoodMood = lambda: greedy_jack.Cash > 100`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using some tips from:

[Is it possible to change an instance's method implementation without changing all other instances of the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647586/is-it-possible-to-change-an-instances-method-implementation-without-changing-al)

you can do the following, by using the types module to assign a method to the object created without affecting the class. You need to do this because a function does not automatically receive the self object as the first variable, but a method does.

```
import types

joe = Person()
bob = Person()

joe.SayHi()
>>> Hello!

def greedy_has_good_mood(self):
    return self.Cash > 100

joe.HasGoodMood = types.MethodType(greedy_has_good_mood, joe)


joe.SayHi()
>>> Hmpf.
bob.SayHi()

>>> Hello!
```

Answer (score 12):

When you write a `def` in a class, and then call it on an instance, that's a method, and the mechanics of method-calling will fill in the `self` argument when you call it.

By assigning to `HasGoodMood` in your instance, you are not putting a new method there, but putting a function into the attribute. You can read the attribute to get the function, and call it, and though that looks like a method call, it's just calling a function that happens to be stored in an attribute. You won't get the `self` parameter supplied automatically.

But you already know what `self` is going to be, since you're assigning this function into one particular object.

```
greedy_jack.HasGoodMood = (lambda self=greedy_jack: self.Cash > 100)
```

This associates the function argument `self` with the current value of the variable `greedy_jack`.

Lambdas in Python can only be one line. If you needed a longer function, you could use a `def` instead.

```
def greedy_jack_HasGoodMood(self=greedy_jack):
    return self.Cash > 100

greedy_jack.HasGoodMood = greedy_jack_HasGoodMood
```

For a less hacky solution, see [Andrew McDowell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52293247/3890632).

Comment: It would be good if you said something about descriptors and method binding, to explain what the OP's actual problem is. However, while I'm not a big fan of your band-aid solution, I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: Why make the function take an argument at all? Something like `greedy_jack_HasGoodMood(temperate_sarah)` would not make sense, for example.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye The argument is needed to "save" the greedy_jack object reference together with the function in the form of a default argument. Otherwise, the function would look for any object called "greedy_jack" in its execution scope, and fail if none exists. This is a frequent catch with using lambdas...

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is the way to go.

It can be something as simple as:

```
class Person(object):
    Cash = 100
    def HasGoodMood(self):
        return self.Cash > 10

    def SayHi(self):
        if self.HasGoodMood():
            print('Hello!')
        else:
            print('Hmpf.')


class newPersonObject(Person):
    def HasGoodMood(self):
        return self.Cash > 100

>>> greedy = newClassPerson()
>>> greedy.SayHi()
hmpf
```

When you do `greedy_jack.HasGoodMood = lambda self: self.Cash > 100` you're somewhat doing the same thing. You're only overriding `greedy_jacks` attributes. Using the way mentioned about, you can create greedy people, happy people, forever unhappy people, hippies etc.

A better option in my opinion would be to accept cash a parameter while defining the object. Hence, you can dynamically make people greedy or normal. (not tested)

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, cash_to_be_happy):
        self.cash = cash_to_be_happy

    def HasGoodMood(self, has_money):
        return has_money > self.cash

    def SayHi(self, has_money):
        if self.HasGoodMood(has_money):
            print('Hello!')
        else:
            print('Hmpf.')

>>> joe = Person(100)
>>> joe.SayHi(150)
Hello!
>>> greedy_joe = Person(200)
>>> greedy_joe.SayHi(150)
Hmpf
```

Comment: See the disclaimer: These are correct and definitely preferable solutions for a real scenario, however, the question is specifically not asking for them.